# how to call newsletter subscription part in a specific page without XML in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to call the newsletter subscription part in a specific page.I don't want it in header.So I turned off it by disabling newsletter.xml page. To call compare product we use

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getListUrl() ?>
```

Now by using php how can I call the newsletter subscription page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place this code where ever you want newsletter box... Enough...

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: if I want to open this newsletter block in a popup like fancybox then what should the href?

I used this code:
$("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
     href : "<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml() ?>",
     type : 'iframe',
     padding : 5
    });
   });

but its not working...

Comment: no..its not good.. Fancy box always works by calling it with div ID. so place the newsletter code in a DIV and give it with an ID and call that ID in the fancybox script.